# How to click a button on System Preferences using applescript?

Tags: applescript, system-preferences

I am trying to write an applescript to change hot corners settings in System Preferences.

[image: system preferences, desktop and screen saver pane]

Here is what I have got until now.

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.desktopscreeneffect"
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Preferences"
        click button "Hot Corners..."
    end tell
end tell
```

But I get this error:`error "System Events got an error: Can’t get button \"Hot Corners...\" of process \"System Preferences\"." number -1728 from button "Hot Corners..." of process "System Preferences"`. I would appreciate anyone explaining what is going wrong in here, plus is there any way to get properties(such as available buttons) of a pane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
click button "Hot Corners..."
```

To:

```
click button "Hot Corners…" of tab group 1 of window 1
```

Note the use of `…`, an *ellipsis* vs. `...` three *dots*, as well as the missing **UI Scripting** hierarchal *elements*.

---

After the `click` line of *code*, and just to get the various **UI elements** you'll need to interact with, use the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* to get that info:

```
get UI elements of sheet 1 of window 1
get UI elements of group "Active Screen Corners" of sheet 1 of window 1
```

<sup>These lines of *code* do not remain in the finished script.</sup>

---

That all said, this was mainly to point out what was wrong with the *code* in your question, however the approach in the other answer is the way to go to get to the **Hot Corners**.

---

**Update to address comment…**

> what does it mean 'UI Scripting hierarchical elements"

From the **AppleScript** dictionary for **System Events**:

> **UI element** *n* : A piece of the user interface of a process

What this means is there is a hierarchy to the *elements* that comprise the **User Interface**, e.g., as shown in the line of *code*:

```
button "Hot Corners…" of tab group 1 of window 1
```

As illustrated in the top section of the following screen shot of **Accessibility Inspector**, a part of **Xcode**:

[image]

Here is one showing one of the hot corners I have set to show the **Desktop**:

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot. But what does it mean 'UI Scripting hierarchical elements"?

Comment: @Arman, RE: "what does it mean 'UI Scripting hierarchical elements"" --  See the **Update to address comment…** section of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you mentioned in your question which drop-down menu in the hot corners that you want to select… I could have posted that additional code in my solution.

This AppleScript code works for me using the latest version of macOS Big Sur.

```
(* Quits "System Preferences" If Running *)

if application "System Preferences" is running then ¬
    do shell script "killall 'System Preferences'"

(* Makes Sure "System Preferences" Is Not Running
Checking Every 1/10 Of A Second Before Moving On 
To The Next Command*)

repeat until application "System Preferences" is not running
    delay 0.1
end repeat

tell application "System Preferences"
    
    (* Launches "System Preferences" Without Bringing It
    To The Foreground, Going Directly To The Window Where You Can
    `click button "Hot Corners..."` *)
    
    reveal anchor "ScreenSaverPref_HotCorners" of ¬
        pane id "com.apple.preference.desktopscreeneffect"
    
    (* Makes Sure anchor "ScreenSaverPref_HotCorners" exists
    Checking Every 1/10 Of A Second Before Moving On 
    To The Next Command*)
    
    repeat while not (exists of anchor "ScreenSaverPref_HotCorners" of ¬
        pane id "com.apple.preference.desktopscreeneffect")
        delay 0.1
    end repeat
    
    (*.Makes application "System Preferences"
    The Frontmost Visible App, Allowing You To Perform
    Any Click Commands *)
    activate
end tell

delay 0.1
tell application "System Events"
    (* "Upper Left Dropdown Menu (pop up button 1) This Can Also Be Repeated
    For `(pop up button 2) <-- Bottom Left, (pop up button 3) <-- Upper Right,
     & (pop up button 4) <-- Bottom Right" *)
    
    (*. By Now You Should Start Understanding The Purpose And Function
     Of These Repeat Loops *)
    
    repeat while not (exists of pop up button 1 of group 1 of sheet 1 of window ¬
        "Desktop & Screen Saver" of application process "System Preferences")
        delay 0.1
    end repeat
    
    click pop up button 1 of group 1 of sheet 1 of window ¬
        "Desktop & Screen Saver" of application process "System Preferences"
    delay 0.1
    
    repeat while not (exists of menu item "Launchpad" of menu 1 of ¬
        pop up button 1 of group 1 of sheet 1 of window "Desktop & Screen Saver" of ¬
        application process "System Preferences")
        delay 0.1
    end repeat
    
    -- Replace "Launchpad" Which Which Ever You Want
    click menu item "Launchpad" of menu 1 of pop up button 1 of ¬
        group 1 of sheet 1 of window "Desktop & Screen Saver" of ¬
        application process "System Preferences"
    delay 0.3
    click UI element "OK" of sheet 1 of window ¬
        "Desktop & Screen Saver" of application process "System Preferences"
end tell
delay 0.5
tell application "System Preferences" to quit
```

[image]

Comment: I would appreciate it if you could provide some explanation to the code

Comment: @Arman I added some comments to the code which should explain what’s going on with a little more detail. I also added an animation which should help visualize what each step of the code does.

Comment: thanks a lot. that gave me an idea of what I should do